# MySQL query fails to run, but no error displayed

Tags: mysql, sql, moodle

When i enter this SQL snippet into **phpMyadmin** nothing happens, and no error message is returned.

What can I do to fix it?

```
CREATE DATABASE `moodle` 
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;

CREATE USER ‘moodle-owner’@’localhost’; 
CREATE USER ‘moodle-owner’@’127.0.0.1’;
CREATE USER ‘moodle-owner’@’::1′;

SET PASSWORD FOR ‘moodle-owner’@’localhost’ = PASSWORD(‘moodle123$%’);
SET PASSWORD FOR ‘moodle-owner’@’127.0.0.1’ = PASSWORD(‘moodle123$%’);
SET PASSWORD FOR ‘moodle-owner’@’::1′ = PASSWORD(‘moodle123$%’);
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: thank you! nothing happans only shows its loading for a second :(

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what version of MySQL you are running, but in 5.7, the `SET PASSWORD` is deprecated. Try setting the user passwords with `IDENTIFIED BY` in the same query as `CREATE USER`.

```
CREATE USER 'moodle-owner'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'moodle123%'; 
CREATE USER 'moodle-owner'@'127.0.0.1' IDENTIFIED BY 'moodle123%';
CREATE USER 'moodle-owner'@'::1' IDENTIFIED BY 'moodle123%';
```

Comment: libmysql - mysqlnd 5.0.11-dev - 20120503 - $Id: 76b08b24596e12d4553bd41fc93cccd5bac2fe7a $  i have already tried it but nothing happans... i am using XAMP 3.2.2